Query: Is there a Feature in ROS2-Humble that enables publisher to publish message only when at least one subscriber connected at the other end
Query: Is there a Feature in ROS2-Humble that enables publisher to publish message only when at least one subscriber connected at the other end.
I found FastDDS 2.6.9 that is used as the bottom layer of ros has a variable(current_count_change) within the publisher listener class is used with in the FastDDS Helloworld example to prevent the write until a matched subscriber connected.

Here you can see some flags checks before write function call
Is there any similar feature or is there any control of such variable available at ROS2 application layer?

please do not post a picture of text ... post the text instead ... use the edit button to update your post

I am not aware if there are more specific functions for enable that inside the publisher itself. However, you can handle that with the logic of your program with the functions pub->get_subscription_count() and get_intra_process_subscription_count().
    bool publish_flag = (pub->get_subscription_count() + pub->get_intra_process_subscription_count()) > 0;
        
    if (publish_flag)
    {
        pub->publish(msg);
    }

See it in this example, publishing pointclouds in the bonxai_server

Hey its working, Thanks @ivrolan

Implemented the pub->get_subscription_count() at publisher side and it seems working, and I have a new concern that, I face initial data loss for some conditions where publisher start publishing data when identifying a subscriber, but the subscriber takes some time to identify the publisher. I need a solution that the publisher should start publishing after subscriber identifies the publisher. is there any flag or method in ROS2 application layer for this purpose?

does increasing the queue size of the subscriber improve this, so no messages are lost when new ones come?

I am running in a environment where tight memory concerns,.
